# Divide TRUE-FALSE matrix and output ratio

Tags: r

I would like to divide df1 on df2 and as output I would like the ratio of the number of "TRUE" in each column between df1 and df2. For instance in column 1 of df1 there is 2 TRUE and in column 1 one df2 there is 2 TRUE, so the output there is 1 (2/2).

I am not sure how to define the TRUE FALSE during division.

df1:

```
 org1 TRUE TRUE FALSE
 org2 FALSE TRUE TRUE
 org3 TRUE TRUE TRUE
 org4 FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

df2:

```
 org1 TRUE FALSE FALSE
 org2 FALSE FALSE TRUE
 org3 TRUE TRUE TRUE
 org4 FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

out:

```
 1 3 1
```

**Edit: Data creation code.**

To read in the data to an R session run the following code.

```
df1 <- scan(what = logical(), text = "
TRUE TRUE FALSE
FALSE TRUE TRUE
TRUE TRUE TRUE
FALSE FALSE TRUE
")
df1 <- matrix(df1, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 4)


df2 <- scan(what = logical(), text = "
TRUE FALSE FALSE
FALSE FALSE TRUE
TRUE TRUE TRUE
FALSE FALSE TRUE
")
df2 <- matrix(df2, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 4)
```

Comment: As simple as `colSums(df1)/colSums(df2)`. Also, see my edit: the way you posted the data is not copy&pasteable.

Comment: `colSums(df1) / colSums(df2)` produces the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the aim is to divide the number of TRUE entries in columns of `df1` by those of `df2`, then

```
colSums(df1) / colSums(df2)
# [1] 1 3 1
```

This is because when you sum loigcal TRUE becomes 1 and FALSE becomes 0.